# Hardware Errors on Freshly Upgraded Computer

Tags: freeze, reboot

I installed a few days ago a new motherboard, CPU and RAM in my computer, practically building it anew. The operating system I installed is openSUSE.

After that my PC doesn't come back from suspend mode by using neither the keyboaord or mouse. Furthermore after a day or two after leaving my PC turned on all night, I found it in the morning completely frozen (mouse pointer frozen, time frozen 5 before the current time etc).

Furthermore, yesterday while working the PC froze completely out of the sudden for a minute and then it resumes working, but in the task manager's graph I saw the CPU cores jumping like crazy.

At last today while working, out of the blue the PC restarted and while booting it showed the following message:

```
[0.312256] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[0.312312] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 5: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
[0.312315] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 mce: ADDR 1ffff814f3510 mce: MISC d012000101000000
```

I am not sure whether that was the exact or whole message as it dissapeared quickly. What I pasted was the message I found in the logs and I think it is the one presented while booting.

It is important to say that I don't know whether all the other issues I mentioned are relevant but I listed them in case they are.

For a PC with completely new hardware, what is the problem? As it says "hardware error" I am seeing it as serious.

**PC SPECS**

1. The motherboard is MSI A320M PRO-VH PLUS(MS-7B07)
2. The CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
3. The RAM is HyperX HX424C12PB3/8 1.2 Volt DDR4 2400 MHz

**EDIT**

It just restarted again. The error message seems to be:

```
[0.297216] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[0.297253] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 4: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: baa0000000060185
[0.297256] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 mce: MISC d012000101000000 mce: SYND 2d030000 mce: IPID b000000000 mce: 
[0.297259] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1515696544 SOCKET 0 APIC 4 microcode 8001126
```

Comment: What is your motherboard? What is your memory? Is the memory compatible with the motherboard in terms of timing, voltage, supported brand, etc?

Comment: @EricF I will add them in the question.

Comment: Am I blind or did you not add them to the question?

Comment: @EricF I am searching about the RAM. I installed lshw and I am trying to familiarize myself with it.

Comment: Memory seems compatible. Try running MemTest86 on your memory and stress test your cpu. When stress testing the CPU see if that starts to trigger errors or it shuts down then. It seems very possible that something is wrong with your CPU based on your errors you posted

Comment: Have you tried disconnect vga output and reconect?
I had same trouble (in db15 didn't woke, in Hdmi worked fine)
Latest bios; Drivers; updates.
Asus prime a320m-a; AMD Ryzen 3 2200g(vega 8);8Gb ddr4 adata 2666